# Manipulating the day of the year

Tags: bash, cron

I want to get the day of the year and subtract one then mod by three. It is a switch for running my scripts within crontab.

```
if (((date(%j) -1) %3))
 echo 'hello'
 exit()
else
 echo hi
fi
```

This is just to test that it is working, however I am getting

```
./getdate.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./getdate.sh: line 4: `fi'
```

This could be trivial for some of you but I am still very new to bash.

Thanks

Comment: There are a number if issues with that script, if it's intended to be Bash. Have you tried http://www.shellcheck.net ?

Comment: @Biffen I didn't even know that was a site, I'll go check it out.

Comment: Also note that `date +%j` (which I assume you meant) prints leading zeros, which Bash will think is an octal number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you meant to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( ( $(date +%-j) - 1 ) % 3 ))
then
  echo 'hello'
  exit
fi

echo hi
```

- Always use a shebang.
- To execute `date` and use what it prints wrap it in `$()`.
- Arguments to commands, in this case `date`, just follow the command (and a space); no brackets.
- `date` wants a `+` to prefix the format.
- `%j` will print leading zeros, which Bash will take to mean the number is octal. Use `%-j` to not get such zeros.
- I think you want to subtract *before* modulus: Use brackets for ordering.
- `if` needs a `then`.
- `exit` should not have brackets.
- No need for an `else` after an `exit`.